# How do I dynamically read audio samples using Android media 3?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I want to read dynamically audio samples for certain range of time from video source multiple times. Can I achive this using media3 Exoplayer? If I can how do I do it? Thank you.

How to use Android Jetpack Media 3 with  code snippets.